# Gather statistics for shared project

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have a C# solution with 3 projects.

- App.Console\App.Console.csproj
- App.Web\App.Web.csproj
- App.Shared\App.Shared.csproj

Both `App.Console` and `App.Web` reference `App.Shared`.  Currently, I build each project separately as they have slightly different MSBuild arguments.

My current build process is as follows

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyApp" /n:"My App" /v:"1.0"
msbuild.exe msbuild App.Console\App.Console.csproj /t:'Rebuild' /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=C:\Out\Console
msbuild.exe msbuild App.Web\App.Web.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=C:\Out\Web
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

I see statistics for both `App.Console` and `App.Web`, however, **statistics for `App.Shared` is missing**.  Instead, I notice a warning in the SonarQube runner output.

> WARNING: Duplicate project GUID: "21889c3d-d9c4-40d6-a4e4-971735d19ee2". Check that the project is only being built for a single platform/configuration and that that the project guid is unique. The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: C:\Projects\MyApp\App.Shared\App.Shared.csproj

I believe this warning is the root of my problem.

If I do the following:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyConsoleApp" /n:"My Console App" /v:"1.0"
msbuild.exe msbuild App.Console\App.Console.csproj /t:'Rebuild' /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=C:\Out\Console
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyWebApp" /n:"My Web App" /v:"1.0"
msbuild.exe msbuild App.Web\App.Web.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=C:\Out\Web
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

I now have 2 separate projects in SonarQube which both contain statistics for `App.Shared`.  This is bad because this information is duplicated between the two projects and does not accurately give me an overall technical debt for my solution.

I have been able to get all three set of statistics in one project by building the solution only:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyApp" /n:"My App" /v:"1.0"
msbuild.exe msbuild App.sln /t:'Rebuild' /p:Configuration=Release
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

This is *not ideal* because building the solution does not build the web project the way I need, thus I must do a 2nd build **after** SonarQube completes (build the way *I* need it, not the way SonarQube wants it).

Is it possible to run `msbuild` multiple times in-conjunction with the SonarQube MSBuild runner and get one set of complete statistics?

Answer (score 1):

In the shared app, you can conditionally set a `<SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>` property, such that it will be set only when building either `App.Web` or `App.Console`.

You can find a proposal on how to achieve this in the Microsoft ALM Rangers guide to SonarQube under Appendix 3, "Explicitly associating an MSBuild project with a SonarQube project": http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/sq-setup-guide-for-dotnet-users.html

Comment: I'll give this a try, can you answer whether it's typical for the behavior I am facing, if a file analyzed twice, you don't get analysis for it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that you have an extra *.sln file in your solution.  I encountered this when there was an old, dormant .sln file in a project folder.  Deleting it resolved the issue.