# Duplicate project GUID with MSBuild Runner

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, biztalk, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, btdf

I have a solution with three projects which fails to be analyzed by SonarQube. It's a c# project, a BizTalk project (btproj) and a test project. The BizTalk and test-project both has project references to the c# project, while the test project has references to both other projects.

When the projects starts the analysis both the BizTalk project and the C# project are noted as duplicate projects, and therefore ignored. If i remove the test-project only the C# project are marked as duplicate.

I've tried different build configuration and CPU mixup, but am unable to produce any different result. We have several other solutions that also has project references that does not give these errors.

```
2015-11-27T08:31:31.0581917Z WARNING: Duplicate project GUID: "5d988c42-d59d-411c-82ed-fe708e943424". Check that the project is only being built for a single platform/configuration and that that the project guid is unique. The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: D:\agent\_work\46e3aa1b\Integrations\Components\Components.csproj 
2015-11-27T08:31:31.0581917Z WARNING: Duplicate project GUID: "5d988c42-d59d-411c-82ed-fe708e943424". Check that the project is only being built for a single platform/configuration and that that the project guid is unique. The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: D:\agent\_work\46e3aa1b\Integrations\Components\Components.csproj
2015-11-27T08:31:31.0581917Z WARNING: Duplicate project GUID: "c7450074-451b-45f0-9059-5349eab6860e". Check that the project is only being built for a single platform/configuration and that that the project guid is unique. The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: D:\agent\_work\46e3aa1b\Integrations\Orchestration\Orchestrations.btproj
2015-11-27T08:31:31.0581917Z WARNING: Duplicate project GUID: "c7450074-451b-45f0-9059-5349eab6860e". Check that the project is only being built for a single platform/configuration and that that the project guid is unique. The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: D:\agent\_work\46e3aa1b\Integrations\Orchestration\Orchestrations.btproj
```

I am aware that BizTalk projects is not supported by SonarQube. However, most of all business logic is placed in the c# class library, and I would assume its not related to this.

Comment: 1. Are you building and invoking the SonarQube analysis using TFS Build, XAML Build or by directly calling msbuild and the sonarqube.msbuild.runner executable? 2. If you build just your BizTalk project and take a look at the logs, can you see the "Build" task being invoked twice?

Comment: I wonder if this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996594/using-sonar-msbuild-runner-with-pispackaging-true/34138637#34138637

Comment: It looks like the BizTalk targets do invoke a second build as Bogdan suggests, which is why two ProjectInfo.xml files are produced. Fortunately, the BizTalk targets have a property that lets you detect whether the first or second build is being executed. Try adding the following at the end of your .btproj file, just before the closing </Project> tag: 

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(SecondBuild)==true">
    <SonarQubeTempPath></SonarQubeTempPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

This should stop the second ProjectInfo.xml from being written.

Answer (score 1):

This will occure if your using BTDF for your deployment and you copy the config file from another project. this will contain the same GUID as the previously deployed project.